Extra \fi error when listing inside a custom environment
I am trying to write a solutions environment sol which I can use to write solutions within assignments. There are two reasons for the environment,

Solutions may be different colour.
Solutions can be toggled to produced solution keys/plain assignments.

Here is what I have,
\documentclass{article}
\title{Test Document}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{xcolor, ifthen, listings}


\newboolean{solution}
\setboolean{solution}{true}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sol}{O{blue} +b}{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{\leavevmode\color{#1}\ignorespaces#2}{}%
}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document} \maketitle

\noindent Question 1. What is two times two?

\begin{sol}
  It is four,
  \[
    2 \times 2 = 4
  \]
  Which is also $\sqrt{16}$.
\end{sol}

\noindent Question 2. Give Python code for adding two twos?

\begin{sol}
  The code is given in listing \ref{code}.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=python, caption={Python code.}, label=code]
x = 2 + 2
print(f'Two plus two is: {x}')
\end{lstlisting}

  As seen above, we know that two twos are four.
\end{sol}

\end{document}

It works except when I put a listing environment within the solution environment as seen in the second question. Where I get the,
ERROR: Extra \fi.

--- TeX said ---
\lst@next ->\fi 
                \lst@next 
l.38 \end
         {sol}

As a side note that may also be a symptom of the same problem, Tex also does not find the reference when the listing is inside the solutions environment.

It's generally a bad idea to have verbatim material as the argument to a command.

How else one might go about implementing the same functionality?

Are you able to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document? If so, the posting How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX? may be of interest to you.

It's generally not a good idea to have verbatim material in the argument to a command.
Use comment instead.
\documentclass{article}
\title{Test Document}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\usepackage{comment}

\lstset{columns=flexible}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{sol}{O{blue}}{%
  \leavevmode\color{#1}\ignorespaces
}{\ignorespacesafterend}
%\excludecomment{sol}

\begin{document} \maketitle

\noindent Question 1. What is two times two?

\begin{sol}
  It is four,
  \[
    2 \times 2 = 4
  \]
  Which is also $\sqrt{16}$.
\end{sol}

\noindent Question 2. Give Python code for adding two twos?

\begin{sol}
  The code is given in listing \ref{code}.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=python, caption={Python code.}, label=code]
x = 2 + 2
print(f'Two plus two is: {x}')
\end{lstlisting}

  As seen above, we know that two twos are four.
\end{sol}

\end{document}


If you remove the % from the \excludecomment{sol} line, you get no solution.


Do we need the \lstset{columns=flexible}?

@scribe Yes, if you want a sensible typesetting
